# How change radio button of Radio Button Group in cell of Table programatically?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to change the selected radio button in group of radio button in cell table programatically.
I try to recreate table after change the status in piece object but if I have many records it becomes slow.

I have the next code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QButtonGroup, \
    QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication


class Piece:
    def __init__(self, init, name, status):
        self.init = init
        self.name = name
        self.status = status

class Table(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.debug_data()
        self.fila = 0
        self.init_ui()

    def debug_data(self):
        print("okay")
        self.pieces: [Piece] = []
        self.pieces.append(Piece('2021-01-11 13:52:00', 'Router 234', 1))
        self.pieces.append(Piece('2021-01-11 13:55:00', 'Router AB', 0))
        self.pieces.append(Piece('2021-01-11 14:00:00', 'Router A234E', 1))
        self.pieces.append(Piece('2021-01-11 14:01:00', 'Router Sufle', 0,))

    def _create_buttons(self):
        self.buttons_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.btn_ok_all = QPushButton("All Manual")
        self.btn_no_ok_all = QPushButton("All Automatic")
        self.btn_no_validate_all = QPushButton("All Hybrid")
        self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.btn_ok_all)
        self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.btn_no_ok_all)
        self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.btn_no_validate_all)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.buttons_layout)

    def init_ui(self):
        self.createTable()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._create_buttons()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.show()

    def createTable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ["Init Time", "Name", "Type"])
        self.process_rows()

    def process_rows(self):
        for piece in self.pieces:
            self.add_row(piece)

    def add_row(self, piece):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.fila)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.fila, 0, QTableWidgetItem(piece.init))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.fila, 1, QTableWidgetItem(piece.name))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.fila, 2, self.create_group_radio_button(piece))
        self.fila = self.fila + 1

    def create_group_radio_button(self, piece):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        number_group = QButtonGroup(widget)
        manual = QRadioButton("Manual")
        number_group.addButton(manual)
        automatic = QRadioButton("Automatic")
        number_group.addButton(automatic)
        hybrid = QRadioButton("Hybrid")
        number_group.addButton(hybrid)
        layout.addWidget(manual)
        layout.addWidget(automatic)
        layout.addWidget(hybrid)
        if piece.status == 0:
            hybrid.setChecked(True)
        elif piece.status == 1:
            manual.setChecked(True)
        else:
            automatic.setChecked(True)
        return widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Table()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is the way to change one of them programatically?
How to access the cell widget and select the button to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation for which creating a class is probably the best approach: it improves the object structure and allows creation of functions that give easier access to it.

```
class PieceSelector(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, piece):
        super().__init__()
        self.piece = piece

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.number_group = QButtonGroup(self)
        manual = QRadioButton("Manual", 1)
        self.number_group.addButton(manual)
        automatic = QRadioButton("Automatic", 2)
        self.number_group.addButton(automatic)
        hybrid = QRadioButton("Hybrid", 0)
        self.number_group.addButton(hybrid)
        layout.addWidget(manual)
        layout.addWidget(automatic)
        layout.addWidget(hybrid)
        self.number_group.button(piece.status).setChecked(True)

    def get_status(self):
        return self.number_group.checkedId()

    def set_status(self, status):
        self.number_group.button(status).setChecked(True)
```

Then you just add the widget by creating the instance and get it back using `cellWidget()`:

```
    def add_row(self, piece):
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(piece.init))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(piece.name))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, PieceSelector(piece))

    def set_status_for_row(self, row, status):
        self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 2).set_status(status)
```